# Saving and restoring app state with native API

Tags: ios, swift, restore

I'm trying to implement saving/restoring state of application.

That code I have:

In `AppDelegate` I've added:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then I have TabBarController implementation that conforms to restoring:

```
final class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        restorationIdentifier = "ContainerVC"
        restorationClass = type(of: self)

        let vc1 = ViewController(with: .green)
        let vc2 = ViewController(with: .red)

        vc1.tabBarItem = .init(title: "green", image: nil, tag: 0)
        vc2.tabBarItem = .init(title: "red", image: nil, tag: 1)


        self.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension TabBarViewController: UIViewControllerRestoration {

    static func viewController(withRestorationIdentifierPath identifierComponents: [String], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {

        let vc = TabBarViewController()

        vc.selectedIndex = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "index")

        return vc
    }

    override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.selectedIndex, forKey: "index")
        print("encoded")
        super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    }

    override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        self.selectedIndex = coder.decodeInteger(forKey: "index")
        super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    }
}
```

Also TabBarViewController is a root ViewController of app window.

I want to, for example, i select second tab - after app terminated its restored and app launched again it should show second tab opened.
I think that encoding should be performed when app terminates. But it's not called. And Decoding not called too. What I make wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `NSCoding` to write data into files, I have used it to save game state and synching over multiple devices via iClould. At beginning it may seems tedious but it pretty straightforward and simple.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or create TabBarViewController manually?

Comment: @ilya i create tabbarcontroller in code

Comment: @ilya and you can see that init?(coder:) are not implemented.